# Plotting dataframe with paramater

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

This is my dataframe

[image]

bedrijf = company

I need to create a function that takes a ticker as a parameter (eg TNET) and creates a graph
with the price of that stock. This is given to start with:

```
def graph(ticker):

stock = pd.DataFrame()
# needs to be replaced with the right code

# assuming the variable stock
# is a dataframe with the data of the stock as a row
# with the specified ticker, the code below ensures
# that x-Axis (xAs) contains the names of the columns and y-Axis (yAs) contains the values ​​in those columns

xAs = stock.columns[2:26]
yAs = stock.iloc[0,2:26]
```

Answer (score 0):

If ticker is a column then `stock[stock['Ticker']==ticker]` is the dataframe with the input ticker prices.

If ticker is the index then `stock.loc[ticker]` will do the job.